# Does any know how to present a SelectFooViewController like UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I would like to present `SelectFooViewController` like `UIAlertController`.

The context code would be...

```
let vc = SelectFooViewController()
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And it will popup a modal view, top of current view.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle`,`definesPresentationContext` and `modalPresentationStyle`

```
let vc = SelectFooViewController()
vc.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = true
vc.definesPresentationContext = true
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: sorry, I am new to here.

Comment: Hi Varun, can I make the behind view's text color as UIAlertController make? I tried to set front view's background color to Gray and 45% opacity, but the behind view's text color still blue.

Comment: here I've uploaded the full source code to GitHub. https://github.com/jacktsai/studyRenderAsAlertController

Comment: can I make the background view's text color to gray as result of UIAlertController?

Answer (score 0):

First You set the view alpha below 10 in storyBoard which controller you have and use following code...

```
let viewController : SelectFooViewController =     self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Your controller Identifier") as! SelectFooViewController
            viewController.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = true;
            viewController.definesPresentationContext = true;
            viewController.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
            viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext

            self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```